# How to use the eftest library with cider-test-report?

Tags: clojure, cider

The default cider-test-report reporter is clojure.test, but how can one use [eftest](https://github.com/weavejester/eftest) to run by default in cider?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't (you can obviously run it from the REPL, though, but I assume that's not what you meant). CIDER relies on a custom test runner that's part of its `cider-nrepl` middleware and tightly integrates with the rest of CIDER's functionality. As CIDER builds a custom UI for the test runs you don't really benefit much from REPL-oriented runners with it anyways.

Still, with Emacs and CIDER everything is possible.
If you want to build some CIDER integration for `eftest` you can use [kaocha-runner](https://github.com/magnars/kaocha-runner.el) as a source of inspiration.